# C# package for .NET when the project uses .NETFramework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to revive an old project (not mine, https://github.com/Cosmik42/BAP) that's written in C#. I am using Visual Studio.  The program does not compile due to a dependency with the following package:  FastColoredTextBox.

```
this.fastColoredTextBox1 = new FastColoredTextBoxNS.FastColoredTextBox();
```

> The type or namespace name 'FastColoredTextBoxNS' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I use the correct version of the .NET framework, as originally compiled (4.6.1).

However, then I use NuGet to install the FastColoredTextBox package, I get the following error.

What am I doing wrong?

> NuGet\Install-Package : Could not install package 'FastColoredTextBox.Net5 2.16.26'. You
> are trying to install this package into a project that
> targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly
> references or content files that are compatible with that
> framework. For more information, contact the package author.
> At line:1 char:1
> + NuGet\Install-Package FastColoredTextBox.Net5 -Version 2.16.26

Comment: "_then I use NuGet to install the FastColoredTextBox package_" Well, you need to install something that actually supports Framework 4.6.1. Pay attention to the error log messages you included in your question. Yes, go ahead, read them... carefully! ;-)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I am a hobbyist programmer. This package is what is in the project. So I have no choice. I cannot change the environment or the package. Or am I wrong? I really have no idea.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.1 is out of support (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework). The author of the package your app was using may have dropped support for the version that supported 4.6.1 (for example, if a security problem was found, there'd be little reason to issue a new 4.6.1-campatible package if 4.6.1 was out of support). My suggestion, migrate to a later version of the Framework

Comment: Do you think ".Net5" in the package name is just eye candy? Did you actually, really, diligently check which platforms this package really supports? If you cannot change neither the environment nor the package, then there is only one outcome: you won't succeed building your project. There is no magic bullet that allows you to use a package that isn't compatible with the target framework of your project...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace And this is what I do not understand. When I downloaded the project from GitHub and opened it in Visual Studio, it asked for .NETFramework 4.6.1. But then this additional package is for .NET5, which I guess is something completely different?  How did the original programmer compile it, then?  Thank you!

Comment: Since i am not the original programmer i don't know and i can't tell. Doesn't matter anyway, even if i knew. One thing is for sure, though, the original programmer didn't build the project for 4.6.1 with this particular library unless they were a real magician...

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FCTB

Comment: There seems to be more than one NuGet package: [FastColoredTextBox.Net5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastColoredTextBox.Net5/#supportedframeworks-body-tab) (.NET) and [FCTB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FCTB/#supportedframeworks-body-tab) (.NET Framework). There are also some forks.

Comment: @user9938 and Hans: this is likely it. When I googled the package it did not even cross my mind that there could be more targets. I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name, and select **Manage NuGet packages...**. Click the **Installed** tab. Select **FCTB**. Click **Uninstall**. Then search for "FCTB", and re-install it. If you'd like to switch to `PackageReference` (from Packages.config), change the setting in VS (Tools => Options => NuGet Package Manager => General) prior to re-installing. See also [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

1. The .NET framework was correct as 4.6.1. However, a Google search for the FastColoredTextBox toolbox results in a .NET5 package, which is clearly not compatible with the .NET framework. Another package (FCTB) seemed to do the trick.

There seems to be more than one NuGet package: FastColoredTextBox.Net5 (.NET) and FCTB (.NET Framework).

2. Better yet, instead of "guessing" which packages were used, it was better to the following:

In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name, and select Manage NuGet packages.... Click the Installed tab. Select FCTB. Click Uninstall. Then search for "FCTB", and re-install it.

3. Also, the project had to be "cleaned" first and I had to close/open VisualStudio2022 at least once.